# bash return value

Tags: bash

I like to write a script or a function (not sure which one yet) that will be called by another script. The script or function is to generate *several* values. How can I write these in bash so that in the other script I can get the values returned by the script or function?

Examples are specially appreciated!

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5):

Use the Bash variable $IFS (internal field separator)

```
dfunc () {echo "first base:second base:third base:home"}

saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
dval=($(dfunc))    # make an array
IFS=$saveIFS       # put $IFS back as soon as you can, you'll thank me
echo ${dval[1]}
```

Outputs:

> second base

If you use a character that won't appear in your data, for example a colon, then you can use other characters, such as spaces.

And [don't use backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), use `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have the script generating the output send its output to stdout, and have the calling script pull it in with backticks.  Example code:

script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1 2 3 4
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ITEM in `script1.sh`
do
    echo Item = $ITEM
done
```

Comment: Back ticks are a horrible idea.

Comment: Wow, that's harsh.  There's a reason there are two different sets of syntax - sometimes one is more convenient.  Not to mention that some shells (admittedly old and busted ones) don't do $() anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As a string delimited by a well-known character (e.g., the colon, as is the convention for  `$PATH` and the like)?

Comment: After that how do you extract those values? Do you mean function or script? Could you give some examples?

Comment: You can just send them to STDOUT, and capture that with your program, or you can pipe them to a file, and then read the file. If you're using perl you can just do something like:

$output = `myScript.sh`;

Good old perl.

Comment: There are supposed to be backticks "`" around the myScript.sh bit.